# Splitting a string into multiple primitive types

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm writing a program that reads a string from the user and uses it to process a request. After issuing a prompt, I can expect one of three possible responses in the form of either:

1. string string
2. string integer
3. string

Depending on which type of command the user gives, the program is to do a different task. I'm having a difficult time trying to process the users input. To be clear, the user will type the command as a single string, so an example of a user exercising option two might input "age 8" after the prompt. In this example I would like the program to store "age" as a string and '8' as an integer. What would be a good way of going about this?

From what I've gathered on here, using strtok() or boost might be a solution. I've tried both without success however and it would be very helpful if someone could help make things clearer. Thanks in advance

Comment: something like `string str; int num; cin >> str >> num;` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I suppose the only problem would be how to determine if the user gave input in the form of string string, or string, instead of string integer as in the example.

Comment: @Shahbaz: That won't work in case 3. You'd want to read a line, then parse that, perhaps from a `stringstream`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, sorry I understood that the user first gives his choice, then enters one of the three forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting one line of input with `std::getline`, you can use a `std::istringstream` to recycle the text for further processing.

```
// get exactly one line of input
std::string input_line;
getline( std::cin, input_line );

// go back and see what input was
std::istringstream parse_input( input_line );

std::string op_token;
parse_input >> op_token;

if ( op_token == "age" ) {
    // conditionally extract and handle the individual pieces
    int age;
    parse_input >> age;
}
```

Comment: @JaimieKnox Welcome to SO! If this solved your problem, click the green check mark at top left beside this answer.